# How to open an Excel Spreadsheet from SSMS dependant on arguments

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I want to have a system whereby someone who doesn't know any SQL can retrieve a excel spreadsheet based on arguments, such as data based on a list of employees, or up to a certain date, etc.

How would you approach this problem? I am using MS SSMS.

Comment: Create a view for them and let them connect to it from Excel.

Comment: that will not do what I want. There are 1000s of employees which change in the short term so views will not work

Comment: i don't want to create 1000s of views, unless that process can be automatic when the user chooses (somehow, not knowing any sql) who to select

Comment: Why do you need a different view for every employee?   Why can't they all use the same view?